# Making PyCharm 2018 'look' like Sublime text 3

Tags: themes, sublime-text-3, pycharm

I've tested [this similar (and old) topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116290/making-pycharm-look-like-sublime-text) but it's not working as desired.

I think Sublime Text 3 (default) is the ideal color theme:
[image]

But importing the informed `.jar` files, I get something far from the original:
[image]

Is there some way to export the current default Sublime Text 3 to `.jar` and import it to Pycharm to be exactly as SB3?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply changing the color scheme?

Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> set it to Monokai